# does Tcl TSV support passing dictionaries

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I would like to share a dict type variable through TSV, but the TSV documentation doesn't show any support for DICT.  Is there perhaps some alternate way to share a DICT variable through threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TSV sub-package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/tsv.htm) doesn't specifically have support for it; you'd usually use a `tsv::array` for that sort of thing. However, you can also just bring the value in as a string inside a lock, process as a dictionary, and write the result back.

```
# assuming that the main thread shared variable is called FOO and we're using the BAR element of it
tsv::lock FOO {
    # Read the dictionary out
    set mycopy [tsv::get FOO BAR]
    # Do some complicated operation
    dict set mycopy "grill" [expr {2**[dict get $mycopy "quux"]}]
    # Write the updated dictionary back
    tsv::set FOO BAR $mycopy
}
```

In many ways, the list-based commands like `tsv::lappend` are wrappers around the basic `get`/`set` pattern rather like that, except the wrappers are written in C for you. (The TSV sub-package is rather old — the API it presents makes me think it has a similar age-of-last-update to Tcl 8.4 — and doesn't provide specific operations for dictionaries.)

Comment: You could also use the keyed list support in TSV. They're syntactically different to dicts, but provide similar basic operations. (I considered using that syntax for dicts when doing the initial `dict` implementation, but didn't because it made other things possible instead.)

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Does that mean that TSV isn't the right way to share reference data between the master and worker threads?  Is there a better way to do that?